# T-SQL: create column sequence relative to another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sequence

Let's say I have the following table with values

```
StudentNumber      StudentName       Class
---------------------------------------------
      0              'A'              100              
      1              'B'              100              
      0              'C'              200              
      1              'D'              200              
      2              'E'              200
```

I want to declare `StudentNumber` to act as a sequence relative to the class number.

So that If I insert `StudentName='F'` to

- class 100 it will assign it a 2
- class 200 it will assign it a 3
- class 300 it will assign it a 0

If it is not possible using an index. Is it possible "selecting max by class" in the insert command.

(I prefer to do it in a single command to avoid deadlock etc)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (SQL Server 2005). If this approach of setting the variables first does not meet your needs then you might want to consider doing this as an insert trigger and just inserting the name and class values. The DB can then provide the studentNumber value.

```
CREATE TABLE t_sw (
studentNumber INT,
studentName VARCHAR(MAX),
class INT
)
GO


DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @class INT

SET @name = 'F'
SET @class = 300

INSERT INTO t_sw (studentNumber, studentName, class)
SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(studentNumber) + 1, 0), @name, @class
FROM    t_sw
WHERE   class = @class

SELECT * FROM t_sw
```

Comment: These *hand-rolled MAX()+1* approaches work well - if you're testing just in a single-user environment. Under load, on a real server, those approaches **tend to fail miserably** and usually produce duplicates rather sooner than later.....

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to use it with EF?

Comment: Sorry @rails I don't know EF well enough to comment. You may find a trigger based approach to be better.

Comment: @marc_s what would you suggest as the best way to approach this? Would a trigger handle the MAX atomically?